# Sylow subgroups conjugates in a soluble group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Recall that a group G is said:

1) *Sylow $\pi$-connected* if the Sylow $\pi$-subgroups of G are conjugates in G.

2) *Sylow $\pi$-integrated* if every subgroup of G is Sylow $\pi$-connected.

3) *Completely Sylow integrated* if G is Sylow $\pi$-integrated for every set of primes $\pi$.

Now i found in some work (for example in Dixon or Hartley) that:

1) *''For by a well known theorem of P. Hall, a finite completely Sylow
integrated group is soluble...''*

2) *''...and so an arbitrary completely Sylow integrated group is locally soluble''.*

I don't found nowhere a proof for 1); for 2) i must consider a finitely generated (and no necessarily finite) subgroup of a completely Sylow integrated group for proof the locally solubility? 
(pheraps G is assumed locally finite?)

Help me, please.

Comment: Perhaps you could supply a few more definitions. What is a Sylow $\pi$-subgroup when $\pi$ is not prime? Is it the same as a Hall $\pi$-subgroup?

Comment: Also, you should probably explain what you mean by a Sylow subgroup in an infinite group

Comment: Let a group G and a set of primes $\pi$. 1) An element $g\in G$ is said a *$\pi$-element* if $|\langle g\rangle|$ is finite and if prime divisors of $|\langle g\rangle|$ are in $\pi$. 2) G is said a *$\pi$-group* if every element of G is a $\pi$-element. 3) A *Sylow $\pi$-subgroup* of G is a maximal element in the ordered set ({P$\le$ G: P is a $\pi$-group},$\subseteq$)

Comment: Yes, that is the usual definition, but not everyone would be familiar with it (especially with $\pi$ in place of $p$), and it might have been better include in the body of the question.

Comment: I found your quotation in a paper of Hartley, but he was assuming that the groups were locally finite, in which case 2 follows immediately from 1. I haven't found a reference for 1 yet, although you can easily reduce to the case of a simple group in which all proper subgroups are solvable.

Answer (score 7):

I think Question 1 reduces easily to the genuinely well known result of Philip Hall, that if the finite group $G$ has a $p$-complement for all prime divisors $p$ of $|G|$, then $G$ is solvable.

(Recall that a $p$-complement is a subgroup of order $t$, where $|G|=p^kt$ and $p$ does not divide $t$.)

To see that, let $\pi$ be the set of prime divisors of $|G|$, and let $p \in \pi$.

Now let  $\pi' =\pi \setminus \{p\}$, and let
$Q \in {\rm Syl}_q(G)$ with $q \in \pi'$. Then $Q$ is a $\pi'$-group, so $Q$ is contained in some Sylow $\pi'$-subgroup $R$ of $G$. This applies to all $q \in \pi'$, and by hypothesis all Sylow $\pi'$-subgroups are conjugate. So $|R|$ contains a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$ for all $q \in \pi'$, and hence $R$ is a $p$-complement in $G$. Now we can apply Hall's theorem to deduce solvability of $G$.

As I said in my comment, I think Hartley was assuming that the groups in question are locally finite, in which case 2 follows immediately from 1. (In any case without some extra assumption, a Tarski Monster would be a counterexample to 2.)